# Problem in setalpha as a Paint parameter for draw in canvas

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas, android-canvas

I have extend a class from View class to show in my activity
I make a canvas and draw some circles in it
This is my ondraw function for this class

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawColor(Color.BLUE)
        circles.forEach {
            canvas?.drawCircle(it.xc,it.yc,it.radious,it.paint)
        }
    }
```

first i draw a color for background and thene i draw my circles
this is my Paint for circles :

```
val circlePaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.MAGENTA
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        alpha = 120
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,this)
        setMaskFilter(BlurMaskFilter(30f,BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL))
    }
```

my problem is when i run the activity the " alpha = 120 " is effect on both color background and circles ... so my background color is being fade too ...
Is anybody has a solution ?

Comment: no need to add ( Android) to your question title, tags are sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the problem .
if you have something like this problem that when set one of your paint alpha , all of your drawing alpha's change , you should change this parameter in your paint from :

```
 setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,this)
```

to

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null)
```

that's it !